# MongoDB filter an array field by period (start date, end date) using PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, doctrine-odm

I have MongoDB documents with this structure:

```
{
     _id: 1
     dates: [
         ISODate ("2015-08-21T22: 00: 00Z")
         ISODate ("2015-09-27T22: 00: 00Z")
     ],
     ...
}
```

In my example, we see that the document 1 was accessed:

- 2015-08-21
- 2015-09-27

In my application, I can filter by time period (start date, end date).

If in my application I filter the period "2015-09-01 - 2015-09-01":

Logically the document 1 should not be found because it was not consulted during this period. But with my tests, the document 1 is found.

What conditions must I use to filter the data correctly?

I tried that but it's fallible:

```
<?php
$begin = new \DateTime('2015-09-01');
$end = new \DateTime('2015-09-01');

$expr1 = $qb->expr()->field('dates')->gte($begin);
$expr2 = $qb->expr()->field('dates')->lte($end);

$qb
    ->addAnd($expr1)
    ->addAnd($expr2)
    ;
```

Thanks for your help,
Yohann

Comment: If you are expecting to test against each array element individually then you need [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/). Not sure of the doctrine syntax off-hand and don't have anything to test with right now. But that should give you a pointer. Also correctly tagged your question to make it visible to the right people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone, I solved the problem with your answers, full tested.

Hard way to do this with the doctrine odm, here is the solution:

```
<?php
$begin = new \DateTime($options['begin']);
$end = new \DateTime($options['end']);

$expr = $qb->expr()
    ->gte($begin)
    ->lte($end)
;

$exprElementMatch = $qb->expr()->field('dates')->elemMatch($expr);
$qb->addAnd($exprElementMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

**With aggregation**

This is the code snippet for mongoshell you can try

```
> db.collection.aggregate([{$unwind:"$dates"},{$match:{"dates":{$gt:new ISODate("2015-01-01"),$lt:new ISOD
ate("2015-09-01")}}}])
```

**With Find Query**

```
db.collection.find({dates:{$elemMatch:{$gt:new ISODate("2015-01-10"),$lt:new ISODate("2015-09-01")}}},{"dates.$":1})
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer currently marked as solved didn't actually work for me.

Given the following data:

```
{
     _id: 1
     dates: [
         ISODate("2015-08-21T22:01:12Z")
         ISODate("2015-08-22T00:06:45Z")
     ],
     ...
}
```

The following query matches the document above:

```
db.collection.find({dates:{$elemMatch:{$gt:new ISODate("2017-08-21"),$lt:new ISODate("2017-08-22")}}}
```

I was confused and read the [$elemMatch documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) and it states:

> The $elemMatch operator limits the contents of an  field from the query results to contain only the first element matching the $elemMatch condition.

So this simply does not work as expected from this solved question. For my use case I was able to evaluate just the first element in the `dates` array to filter my documents with the following query.

```
db.collection.find({"dates.0":{$gte:new ISODate("2017-07-02"),$lt:new ISODate("2017-07-03")})
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27095246/932396) goes into detail in how to actually query the `dates` array.